# Error Message Question

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, error

I'm new to salesforce and am unsure how to approach this error message. I had created this class that rolls down a Contact Role from a Contact created on a Parent to its children and a trigger that executes on creation. It had worked yesterday but when testing it again I now recieve this error message:

Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)

> There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger LAM_Contact_ReleatedList caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: LAM_Contact_ReleatedList: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, Contact has already been added in that Contact Role: [ContactId, Role]: Class.LAM_RelatedListUpdate.RollContactRolesToAccountChildren: line 36, column 1".

Would someone be able to explain to me what changed and what to look at to fix this issue? thank you.

Apex Code:

```
public class LAM_RelatedListUpdate {
    Public static void RollContactRolesToAccountChildren(List<Contact> con){
        //variables for the account lam record types
         Id LAMCRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('LAM Customer Account').getRecordTypeId();//get recordtypeID of Large Customer
         Id LAMSRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('LAM Site Account').getRecordTypeId();//get recordtypeID of Large Customer
         Id LAMDRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('LAM Division Account').getRecordTypeId() ;//get recordtypeID of Large Customer


        //list of child accounts, parent accounts, contacts and contact roles
        List<Id> accountsFromContacts = new List<Id>();  
        List<Account> parentAccounts = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> listOfAccountChildren = new List<Account>();
        List<AccountContactRole> contactRolesClones = new List<AccountContactRole>();

        System.debug(con);

        for(contact c : con){
            accountsFromContacts.add(c.AccountId);
        }

        parentAccounts = [Select Id, RecordTypeId from Account Where Id = :accountsFromContacts ];


        listOfAccountChildren = [Select Id, RecordTypeId, Parent_Account_for_LAM__c from Account Where Parent_Account_for_LAM__c = :accountsFromContacts ];
        //updates the contact roles of the child accounts
        for(contact c : con){
            for(Account a : listOfAccountChildren ){
                if(isMatchingRecord(a.Parent_Account_for_LAM__c, parentAccounts) ){
                    AccountContactRole cloneConatactRole = new AccountContactRole( AccountId = a.id , ContactId = c.Id,  Role = c.Customer_Role__c  );
                    contactRolesClones.add(cloneConatactRole);
                }
            }
        }


        upsert contactRolesClones;

    }
    //checks that the parent account is of these lam record types, and if the parentId matches the one of the child
    public static Boolean isMatchingRecord(Id ParAcc, List<Account> acc){
         Id LAMCRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('LAM Customer Account').getRecordTypeId();//get recordtypeID of Large Customer
         Id LAMSRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('LAM Site Account').getRecordTypeId();//get recordtypeID of Large Customer
         Id LAMDRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('LAM Division Account').getRecordTypeId() ;//get recordtypeID of Large Customer
        for (account a: acc){
            if (a.Id == ParAcc ){
                if(a.recordtypeid == LAMCRecordTypeId  ||  a.recordtypeid == LAMDRecordTypeId || a.recordtypeid == LAMSRecordTypeId){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger LAM_Contact_ReleatedList on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    LAM_RelatedListUpdate.RollContactRolesToAccountChildren(trigger.new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can handle this scenarios:

1. Verify if the contact is already exists in the contact role and if so then eliminate those before putting into the `AccountContactRole` list.
2. Use `Database.insert(recordToInsert, allOrNone)` and `Database.update(recordToUpdate, allOrNone)` method with `allOrNone=false`, so that if any error occurs whole execution will not get stopped.

Put appropriate `Trigger.addError(message)` to show the message along with the above.